# Polar Point Distance

Tags: java, math, equation, points

I am trying to find the distance from one polar point to x (where x is undefined).

Heres what i done have so far,

```
public double dist (p1 x){
  double rad = p1.r + x.r;
  double ang = x.a - p1.a;
  return Math.sqrt(rad-(2*(this.rad*other.rad)*Math.cos(ang))); 
}
```

}

I am getting an error saying that variable `r` and `a` can't be found (I think i have defined them at the top of my code). I am also curious if this looks correct at all.

EDITED

```
public class Dist implements Point{

double rad;
double angl;

public double dist(Point other){
double a1 = rad;
double a2 = other.rad;
doube aTot = (a1 + a2);
double ang = other.angl - angl;
return Math.sqrt(aTot-(2*(a1*a2)*Math.cos(ang)));
}
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete class, which has the minimal amount of code to produce just the error you have trouble with. That is, start with empty class, then add add only relevant stuff from your real code, bit by bit, compiling after every paste and fixing errors as you go on, until you get just the error you can't fix.

Comment: Or, if problem is solved, you could accept (tick mark at upper left corner of answers) an answer (post your own answer if current one answer isn't correct) to mark the question solved.

Comment: just re-edited it, I am curious why the variables rad and angl can't be found by the dist method.

Comment: As a side note, it's usually not necessary to add notes like "EDITED" when you edit the question (don't edit the question so that it *changes* to a different question, just edit it to clarify/fix it, to avoid making any existing answers invalid). Also, the first piece of code should probably be removed from question, it looks like obsolete duplicate of latter piece?

Comment: Uhm, so Point is an interface. Interfaces don't have data members, only method definitions. So, other.rad and other.angl are always wrong, because other is Point, which is an interface. I wonder why you want Dist to implement Point in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

That is a method of your class CLASS_NAME (suppose), so `this.r` is the variable r of the instance of the invoked method, but the object `other` is the problem... where is that object ?

I think you must to pass that object to  the method too.

```
public double dist (p1 x, final CLASS_NAME another){....
```

Comment: I think I may have figure it out, I still need to finish a few methods and run the test, if my method doesn't work Ill let you know.  Thanks

Comment: I am confused on my class name.  public double fist (p1 x) so p1 is in my code, but x is coming from a tester file.  Every time I try to compile, it says that it can't find the symbol.  Any thoughts?

Comment: update the code and add the most important things of the class please

Comment: so Im wondering how my code will be able to recognize Other, as well as the variables Rad and Angl?